# In Chapter 2, is there any way to cure both illnesses?

Tags: kings-quest

In Chapter 2, two of your fellow inmates are sick, and without medicine they will die (on the same day, no less). One prisoner, Bramble, is pregnant with child. The other doomed prisoner is Mr. Fancy Cakes, who (I'm assured) is *totally* a unicorn.

The main problem, aside from figuring out the puzzles to get *anything* done, is that there appears to be only one "miracle cure potion". This sets up the moral dilemma of choosing one over the other.

But is there a way to have my Fancy Cakes, and <s>eat</s> save the pregnant lady too?

Comment: Short answer no. It is not possible. The achievement for saving `everyone` actually does not count both of them. It only counts the one you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the multiple [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kingsquest/comments/3x42cd/how_am_i_suppose_to_save_everyone_its_impossible/) and [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/345390/discussions/0/487877107132650890/) discussions around this issue all having the same conclusion of not being able to save both Bramble and Mr Fancy Cakes, I would call this answered as "No".

I believe this is intentional to make the player decide whether to save everyone or collect all pages.